# Failing to get any PyOpenGL functions working, keeps getting error 1282 invalid operation on Windows

Tags: python-3.x, opengl, pycharm, pyopengl

I've been searching in Google and Stackoverflow for days now trying to solve this peculiar problem... tried out over 50+ ways suggested by the OpenGL/Python community. My 1st time trying to use PyOpenGL within PyCharm IDE... or Python cmd line.

- Windows 10 OS
- no GPU, just Intel UHD 64-bit graphics latest driver and tested OK with OpenGL v4
- installed Python 3.10
- installed latest pyopensl, pygame, etc into PyCharm and C:\Python310\
- even tried installing PyOpenGL via wheel file... PyOpenGL-3.1.6-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl and PyOpenGL_accelerate-3.1.6-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl

The following simple std codes I got from the WWW community keeps throwing...

```
OpenGL.error.GLError: GLError(
    err = 1282,
    description = b'invalid operation',
    baseOperation = glGenTextures,
    pyArgs = (
        1,
        <object object at 0x000001E4412E72A0>,
    ),
```

Here the full codes...

```
import os
import pygame
from OpenGL.GL import *

class OBJ:
    generate_on_init = True
    @classmethod
    def loadTexture(cls, imagefile):
        surf = pygame.image.load(imagefile)
        image = pygame.image.tostring(surf, 'RGBA', 1)
        ix, iy = surf.get_rect().size
        # Creating Texture
        texid = glGenTextures(1)
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texid)
        # texture wrapping params
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT)
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT)
        # texture filtering params
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR)
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR)
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, ix, iy, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image)

        return texid

    @classmethod
    def loadMaterial(cls, filename):
        contents = {}
        mtl = None
        dirname = os.path.dirname(filename)

        for line in open(filename, "r"):
            if line.startswith('#'): continue
            values = line.split()
            if not values: continue
            if values[0] == 'newmtl':
                mtl = contents[values[1]] = {}
            elif mtl is None:
                raise ValueError("mtl file doesn't start with newmtl stmt")
            elif values[0] == 'map_Kd':
                # load the texture referred to by this declaration
                mtl[values[0]] = values[1]
                imagefile = os.path.join(dirname, mtl['map_Kd'])
                print("imagefile=", imagefile)
                mtl['texture_Kd'] = cls.loadTexture(imagefile)
            elif values[0] == 'map_Bump':
                # ignore, do nothing
                print("ignoring... ", values[0])
            else:
                print(values[1:])
                mtl[values[0]] = list(map(float, values[1:]))
        return contents

    def __init__(self, filename, swapyz=False):
        """Loads a Wavefront OBJ file. """
        self.vertices = []
        self.normals = []
        self.texcoords = []
        self.faces = []
        self.gl_list = 0
        dirname = os.path.dirname(filename)

        material = None
        for line in open(filename, "r"):
            if line.startswith('#'): continue
            values = line.split()
            if not values: continue
            if values[0] == 'v':
                v = list(map(float, values[1:4]))
                if swapyz:
                    v = v[0], v[2], v[1]
                self.vertices.append(v)
            elif values[0] == 'vn':
                v = list(map(float, values[1:4]))
                if swapyz:
                    v = v[0], v[2], v[1]
                self.normals.append(v)
            elif values[0] == 'vt':
                self.texcoords.append(list(map(float, values[1:3])))
            elif values[0] in ('usemtl', 'usemat'):
                material = values[1]
            elif values[0] == 'mtllib':
                self.mtl = self.loadMaterial(os.path.join(dirname, values[1]))
            elif values[0] == 'f':
                face = []
                texcoords = []
                norms = []
                for v in values[1:]:
                    w = v.split('/')
                    face.append(int(w[0]))
                    if len(w) >= 2 and len(w[1]) > 0:
                        texcoords.append(int(w[1]))
                    else:
                        texcoords.append(0)
                    if len(w) >= 3 and len(w[2]) > 0:
                        norms.append(int(w[2]))
                    else:
                        norms.append(0)
                self.faces.append((face, norms, texcoords, material))
        if self.generate_on_init:
            self.generate()

    def generate(self):
        self.gl_list = glGenLists(1)
        glNewList(self.gl_list, GL_COMPILE)
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)
        glFrontFace(GL_CCW)
        for face in self.faces:
            vertices, normals, texture_coords, material = face

            mtl = self.mtl[material]
            if 'texture_Kd' in mtl:
                # use diffuse texmap
                glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, mtl['texture_Kd'])
            else:
                # just use diffuse colour
                glColor(*mtl['Kd'])

            glBegin(GL_POLYGON)
            for i in range(len(vertices)):
                if normals[i] > 0:
                    glNormal3fv(self.normals[normals[i] - 1])
                if texture_coords[i] > 0:
                    glTexCoord2fv(self.texcoords[texture_coords[i] - 1])
                glVertex3fv(self.vertices[vertices[i] - 1])
            glEnd()
        glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)
        glEndList()

    def render(self):
        glCallList(self.gl_list)

    def free(self):
        glDeleteLists([self.gl_list])

dir_name = os.getcwd()
OBJ(os.path.join(dir_name, 'models/earth.obj'), swapyz=True)
```

I narrowed down to the "1282 invalid operation" complaint from running ANY glXXXXX() functions. If I removed any glXXXXX() function, it will complain the next glXXXXX() until all of them are removed. I cant even have the simple... texid = glGenTextures(1)

The "earth.obj" I have all its mtl, texture, bump 2D jpg files in same dir as this py file. I tested these 3D/2D files using 3D viewer online to be OK.

Anyone can please give some pointers what is wrong with my OS or graphics driver or packages? Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Where is your main program? Where do you create the OpenGL window and [OpenGL Context](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Context). You cannot use OpenGL without a valid context.

Comment: Hello Rabbid... I followed this http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/documentation/installation.html. I believe I setup a context at ... C:\Python310\venv but still not working.

$ virtualenv oglc-env
$ source oglc-env/bin/activate
(oglc-env)$ pip install PyOpenGL PyOpenGL_accelerate "PyVRML97==2.3.0a4" simpleparse numpy "OpenGLContext==2.2.0a3" pydispatcher pillow

Do you have better help on how to setup OpenGL context within PyCHARM IDE??

Comment: The question is not if you installed OpenLG it correctly, but if you opened the window in your code in a way that supports OpenGL.

Comment: Hi BDL.. sorry for my ignorance bcoz I m new to OpenGL on Windows. Rabbid7 also mentioned "OpenGL window" and you mentioned "opened the window in your code". Which window? Do you mean the window from my py Run? Can you share screenshot or a link reference to guide me? TQ

Comment: @user253751: OpenGL needs an OpenGL context. You can think of it as the place where all OpenGL related states are stored. The context is tied to the Window (or Surface) you are rendering to. If you don't have a context, then all OpenGL commands fail. I have no clue where you get your render window/surface from, but you have to make sure that the window has a context for the OpenGL version you are targeting.

Comment: @user253751: When I call `glGetError()` in an otherwise empty main method on Windows 10, it returns 1282 (INVALID_OPERATION). All methods available in OpenGL 1.1 (those exposed by the default opengl header) can be called without crashing. Methods above 1.1 are crashing. I don't know if python behaves the same way.

Comment: @user253751 and BDL... appreciate for your further insights. They are giving me chance to test what you explained... will update you on the news soon. :-)

Comment: Sorry fellows.. firstly putting glGetError() prior to all other glXXXX() func is causing 1282 error at this glGetError(). 

Secondly, there is no way to install pyOpenGL version 1.1 or even 3.1.5 into my Python 3.10... pip wont allow installation.

I removed my prev pyOpenGL from Python 3.10. Then nav into C:\Python310\venv (where I setup OpenGL context). I activated the context to get (venv)C:\ prompt. I tried installing back pyOpenGL inside the context and then ran my codes above.... still getting 1282 error on all glXXXXX() func.

Comment: TQ TQ fellows... per your hint on "context window", I searched further and finally understood it all from this link.... in fact now glXXXXX() func are all working w/o errors due to the init of context window using package "glfw" (the key!!!)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64137238/python-opengl-will-not-load-texture

In summary for OpenGL to work, it has to setup a context window for the OpenGL to render within that window or else it will complain. Turns out within PyCHARM I dont need pre-setup OpenGL context by using package "glfw"